# How to successfully execute test via phpunit within relationship between two models?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, phpunit, laravel-testing

I'm new in Laravel. I have 2 tables Productions and Products. Also, I have 2 factories ProductionFactory and ProductFactory. I want to test them via phpunit. Their connection is via production_id.

Error is ErrorException: Undefined variable: production.

I don't get it.

Thanks in advance.

This is a code.

ProductionFactory.php

```
        $factory->define(App\Production::class, function (Faker $faker) {
        return [
                'name' =>$faker->name,
            ];
          });
```

ProductFactory.php

```
       $factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
        $production_id = App\Production::pluck('id');

       if(!$production_id->isEmpty()){
          $production = $production_id->random();
       }

    return [
             'id' =>$faker->uuid,
             'name' =>$faker->name,
             'price' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 100, $max = 900),
             'description' =>Str::random(10),
             'production_id'=> $production,
          ];
```

ProductionTest.php

```
           class ProductionTest extends TestCase
            {
              use RefreshDatabase;

             /**
             * A basic unit test example.
             * @test
             * @return void
               */
            public function production()
               {
                   factory(Production::class)->make();
                   $this->assertTrue(true);
               }
           }
```

ProductTest.php

```
           class ProductTest extends TestCase
            {
              use RefreshDatabase;

             /**
             * A basic unit test example.
             * @test
             * @return void
               */
            public function product()
               {
                   factory(Product::class)->make();
                   $this->assertTrue(true);
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what functionality should be tested.

A basic test to check the model relationship is set correctly?

I pushed a working demo to [GitHub (https://github.com/.../laravel-basic-relationship-tests)](https://github.com/jonasemde/laravel-basic-relationship-tests).

**App/Product.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function production()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Production::class);
    }
}
```

**App/Production.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Production extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Product Factory**

```php
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Product as Model;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $production = factory(\App\Production::class)->make();
    $production->save();

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'price' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 100, $max = 900),
        'description' => $faker->text,
        'production_id' => $production->id
    ];
});
```

**Production Factory**

```php
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Production as Model;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name
    ];
});

$factory->afterCreatingState(Model::class, 'seed', function ($production, $faker) {
    $product = factory(\App\Product::class)->make();
    $production->products()->associate($product);
});
```

**Product Test**

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ProductTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function testProductHasWorkingProductionRelationship()
    {
        $product = factory(\App\Product::class)->create();
        $this->assertNotEmpty($product->production);
    }
}
```

**Production Test**

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ProductionTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function testProductionHasWorkingProductRelationship()
    {
        $production = factory(\App\Production::class)->state('seed')->create();
        $this->assertNotEmpty($production->products);
    }
}
```

Hope this is a great starting point for any further tests.

Comment: I have an error. SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'production_id' doesn't have a default value. Production_id is foreign key in table Products, which is related to primary id in table Productions.

Comment: I think this is a migration issue. Compare your migrations with
[these](https://github.com/jonasemde/laravel-basic-relationship-tests/tree/master/database/migrations).

Comment: You use nullable properties in columns. I mustn't use that kind of columns. I know it's a complex problem. Btw, your method works good, but I hope so there is another way to solve this problem, without nullable.

Comment: I edited the answer. It should now work without a production_id nullable field.

Comment: You're right. But, as you can see, my model Production is a little bit different then yours. I have function products() {return $this->hasMany(App\Product::class);} As regards to model Product, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Model Production

```
      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

       class Production extends Model
       {
            use SoftDeletes;
              protected $fillable = [
                 'name',
              ];
             public function products()
               {
              return $this->hasMany('App\Product');

               }
```

Model Product

```
      class Product extends Model
          {

              use SoftDeletes;
               protected $fillable = [
              'id','name','price','description','production_id'
               ];
           public function production()
          {
             return $this->belongsTo('App\Production');
            }
```

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'production_id' doesn't have a default value